# Use current users authentication for URLConnection in JavaEE

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

My users sign into my website using basic authentication. Is there any way I can use an authenticated users details, to act as an authenticator for a URLConnection?....

Something like

```
@get 
@Path("/rest/getInfo)
public String giveMeTheResult(){

   URLConnection conn = new URL("/service/info");
  Authenticator.setDefault(getCurrentUserAuthentication());

   return (String) conn.getContent();

}
```

How do I do the getCurrentuserAuthentication part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is basic auth, it shouldn't be too bad.  I haven't done this but I would think that you could do something like:

```
public String giveMeTheResult(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String[] authChunks = authHeader.split(" ");
    String decodedAuth = new String( Base64.getDecoder().decode(authChunks[1]));
    String[] userInfo = decodedAuth.split(":");
    // user name is userInfo[0], password is userInfo[1]

    // not convinced that this is a good idea because it sets it for all
    Authenticator.setDefault(new PasswordAuthentication(userInfo[0],
                             userInfo[1].toCharArray());

   return (String) conn.getContent();
}
```

But a warning - this is totally untested and there is no error checking!